# How do I disable the hover menu appearing in the lower lefthand corner of the intellij window?

Tags: intellij-idea

How do I disable the menu appearing in the lower lefthand corner of the intellij window?
Is this called the tool menu?
I use hot corners on my macbook and am constantly activating it accidentally.

[image: The menu is appearing in the lower left corner]

Comment: this thing is a part of status bar, you could disable entire status bar from View > Status Bar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a Registry key for that, you can either add

`-Dide.windowSystem.showTooWindowButtonsSwitcher=false`

into [.vmoptions](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/articles/206544869) (`Help` | `Edit Custom VM Options`) or you can press `Help` | `Find Action` | `Registry`, <kbd>Enter</kbd> (or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>/</kbd>) and trigger it in the dialog (start typing the key name for the speed search):

[image: Registry]

This menu can be also disabled by disabling the status bar:

[image: disable status bar]